# Homotopy Invariance: Prism Operator in Hatcher Pg 112, Proof of Prop 2.10

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can someone please help me understand the **prism operator** and how it helps form a **chain homotopy**? A toy example would greatly help! I don't quite understand why $F \circ (\sigma \times {I})$ is needed here and why it is restricted to the $(n+1)$-simplex $[v_0,\dots,v_i,w_i, \dots, w_n ]$.

[image]

Comment: I've read this several times, and I still cannot discern what your actual question is. What part of this argument is causing you concern?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I actually understood it after spending some more time with it. I was confused as to why the restriction was a $(n+1)$-simplex there and what the intuition behind the prism operator was.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679054/in-hatchers-proof-that-two-homotopic-maps-induce-the-same-homomorphism-in-homol?rq=1