# In Hatcher's proof that two homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism in homology what do the prism operators represent?

Tags: algebraic-topology

On page 112 in the proof of Theroem 2.10 Hatcher defines the prism operators given by:

$P(\sigma)=\sum_i(-1)^iF\circ(\sigma\times Id_I)\mid[v_0,\cdots,v_i,w_i,\cdots,w_n]$

$F\circ(\sigma\times Id_I):\Delta^n\times I\rightarrow X \times I \rightarrow Y$, where $F$ is the homotopy from $f$ to $g$ and $\sigma$ is a singular simplex.

Is there an intuative way of thinking about what these operators do? Why is there an alternating sum? I've been tring to think about how an n-simplex in X that can be thought of as the bottom of $\Delta^n\times I$ can be mapped to an (n+1)-simplex in $\Delta^n\times I$ in any meaningful way. In essence I do not understand the link between the prism $\Delta^n\times I$ and the prim operators. Any simple example would be much appreciated.

Edit: In terms of a 1-simplex with prism $\Delta^1\times I$ we have

$P(\sigma)=F\circ(\sigma\times Id_I)\mid[v_0,w_0,w_1]-F\circ(\sigma\times Id_I)\mid[v_0,v_1,w_1]$

This maps a 1-simplex in $X$ to a 2-chain in $Y$ where the boundary is the "square" on the outside of $\Delta^1\times I$. So as I understand it we take some map from the bottom of $\Delta^1\times I$ to $X$ which is a 1-simplex and are then applying this map to a 2-simplex such as $[v_0,w_0,w_1]$. How can we apply a map $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$ to $\Delta^{n+1}$?

Comment: Have you looked at the pictures on that page in Hatcher? Those pictures are there to explain the intuition. If there's something that doesn't make sense about those pictures, could you please edit your question to make it clear exactly what it is that doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having looked at your edit, it seems like the confusion is around understanding how the prism operator is actually *defined*.

It seems like the notation $F\circ(\sigma\times \text{Id}_I)\mid[v_0,w_0,w_1]$ is the source of confusion. You've correctly identified that this map is a map from $\Delta^2$ to $Y$, but it seems like you're not completely clear on how this map is defined. So I'll explain.

The map $F\circ(\sigma\times \text{Id}_I)\mid[v_0,w_0,w_1]$ is a composition of the following three maps.

- The (unique) *affine* map from $\Delta^2$ to $\Delta^1 \times I$ that sends
  $$(0, 0) \mapsto ((0), 0), \ \ \ \ \ (1, 0) \mapsto ((0), 1), \ \ \ \ \ (0, 1) \mapsto ((1), 1).$$
- The map from $\Delta^1 \times I$ to $X \times I$ that sends
  $$ ((t_0), s) \mapsto (\sigma(t_0), s), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for all } (t_0) \in \Delta^1, \ s\in I,$$
  where $\sigma : \Delta^1 \to X$ is the singular $1$-simplex that we started with.
- The map from $X \times I$ to $Y$ that sends
  $$ (x, s) \mapsto F(x, s), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for all } x \in X, \ s\in I,$$
  where $F : X \times I \to Y$ is the homotopy.

[An [affine map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) is a composition of a linear transformation and a translation. An affine map from $\Delta^2$ to some other space is fully specified once you've specified the images of any three points in $\Delta^2$; in particular, it is fully specified once you've specified the images of the three corners of $\Delta^2$. In our example, our affine map maps the triangle $\Delta^2$ *rigidly* onto the triangle in $\Delta^1 \times I$ whose corners are situated at $((0), 0)$, $((0), 1)$ and $((1), 1)$.]

The map $F\circ(\sigma\times \text{Id}_I)\mid[v_0,v_1,w_1]$ is defined in a similar way. The only difference is that the affine map we use is the affine map that sends
$$(0, 0) \mapsto ((0), 0), \ \ \ \ \  (1, 0) \mapsto ((1), 0), \ \ \ \ \ (0, 1) \mapsto ((1), 1).$$

---

**Edit:** I thought I'd expand on this and describe how to prove that
$$ g_\# (\sigma) - f_\# (\sigma) = P (\partial \sigma) + \partial(P(\sigma))$$
when $\sigma$ is a singular $1$-simplex. I'll do so using *my* notation based on affine maps, rather than using Hatcher's notation.

This will help you see where the minus signs come in, as per your request below. And hopefully, it will help you follow the proof in general. (Yes, I also found the Hatcher's proof difficult to understand because of the notation - I didn't get my head around it until I rewrote everything in terms of affine maps.)

So let's get started. As already discussed, we start with a $1$-simplex $\sigma$ on $X$. Applying the prism operator $P$ on $\sigma$, we get $P(\sigma)$, which is a $2$-chain on $Y$:
$$ P(\sigma) = F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0,0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1, 0) \mapsto ((0), 1) \\ (0, 1) \mapsto ((1), 1)} - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0,0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1, 0) \mapsto ((1), 0) \\ (0, 1) \mapsto ((1), 1)}.$$

[image: P sigma]

Applying the boundary operator $\partial$ to $P(\sigma)$, we get $\partial(P(\sigma))$, which is a $1$-chain on $Y$:
$$ \partial P(\sigma) = P(\sigma) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto (1, 0) \\ (1) \mapsto (0, 1)} - P(\sigma) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto (0, 0) \\ (1) \mapsto (0, 1)} + P(\sigma) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto (0, 0) \\ (1) \mapsto (1, 0)}.$$

Substituting in our expression for $P(\sigma)$ and expanding all the terms, we obtain the expression
\begin{align}
\partial P(\sigma) = & \ F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 1) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) } - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((1), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) } \\ & \ - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) } + F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) }\\ & \ + F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((0), 1) } - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 0)}.
\end{align}

[image: partial P sigma]

The two terms on the second line cancel each other out, leaving us with the expression
\begin{align}
\partial P(\sigma) = & \ F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 1) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) } - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((1), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) } \\  & \ + F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((0), 1) } - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 0)} .
\end{align}

Meanwhile, if we apply the boundary operator $\partial$ to $\sigma$, then we get $\partial\sigma$, which is a $0$-chain on $X$:
$$ \partial\sigma = \sigma \circ \text{Affine}_{(.)\mapsto (1) } - \sigma \circ \text{Affine}_{(.)\mapsto (0) }. $$

Applying the prism operator $P$ to $\partial\sigma$, we get $P(\partial\sigma)$, which is a $1$-chain on $Y$:
$$ P(\partial\sigma) = F \circ (\partial\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((.), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((.), 1)}.$$

Substituting in our expression for $\partial\sigma$, we see that
\begin{align}
P(\partial\sigma) = F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((1), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1)} - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((0), 1)}.
\end{align}

[image: P partial sigma]

Thus
\begin{align}
\partial P(\sigma) + P(\partial \sigma) = & \ F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 1) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) }  - F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 0)} .
\end{align}

But $F(x, 1) = g(x)$ and $F(x, 0) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$, since $F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$. So
$$ F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 1) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 1) }  = g \circ \sigma = g_\#(\sigma)$$
and
$$ F \circ (\sigma \times \text{Id}_I) \circ \text{Affine}_{(0)\mapsto ((0), 0) \\ (1) \mapsto ((1), 0)} = f \circ \sigma = f_\#(\sigma).$$

[image: g hash sigma]

Thus
$$ \partial P(\sigma) + P(\partial \sigma) = g_\#(\sigma) - f_\#(\sigma),$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed. The affine map from $\Delta^{n+1}$ to $\Delta^n\times I$ was the gap in my understanding. Am I correct in saying that we are understanding $n$-simplices in $X$ and $Y$ as the $(n+1)$-simplices in the prism, where one vertex does not lie in the $\Delta^n\times \{0\}$ (but in the other end) for the case where we have an $n$-simplex of $X$? I am still unsure as to why the sum is alternating. Is this to account for the orientation of the simplices?

Comment: I can't understand your middle sentence, I'm afraid. But I can answer your final sentence. Why don't I write out the whole of Hatcher's proof in terms of affine maps, and then you'll see why the sum is alternating. In doing so, I'll also make it explicit as to what is a $1$-chain, what is a $2$-chain etc. Gimme a moment...

Comment: @DanDisney Take a look at this edit, where I've written out the remainder of the proof.

Comment: This is fantastic. The affine map notation gives such a clear explination of which parts of the prism $f_\#$ and $g_\#$ are accosiated to and similarly for the boundary terms. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this, I now feel I have the understanding and intutition I was looking for.

Comment: @DanDisney Glad to help! In fact, part of the reason I wrote this out is that it helped _me_ understand this stuff better too. I found this bit of Hatcher _super_ confusing.